# jquery adding an onclick event to a href link

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am converting over from websforms to asp.net mvc and i have a question.

i have a loop that generates links dynamicallly where picNumberLink is a variable in a loop and image is a variable image link.

i want to avoid putting javascript actions inline so in my webforms project is did the following:

```
hyperLink.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:void(viewer.show(" + picNumberlink + "))");
```

what is the equivalent using jquery in asp.net mvc?

I have seen examples of using the $(document).ready event to attach on clicks but i can't figure out the syntax to pass in the picNumberLink variable into the javascript function.

suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT: If you generate your links with the ID of this form:

```
<a id="piclink_1" class="picLinks">...</a>
<a id="picLink_2" class="picLinks">...</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.picLinks').click(function () {
        //split at the '_' and take the second offset
        var picNumber = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
        viewer.show(picNumber);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: where does picNumberLink come from since this is a variable?

Comment: @me - does that make more sense now?

Comment: maybe that is my issue / question.  I just have an image so where can i shove the picNumber into so i would be able to grab it from javascript?  i am not displaying the text

Comment: @me - then see my answer. If you give your picture links the class="picLinks" that will do it.

Comment: but i am not displaying any text in my link . . just the image.. if the number was in the text it would be perfect but its not

Comment: this edit look correct to me but when i click the javascript doesn't seem to fire:

my link code is now:

<a id="picLinks_1" class="picLinks" href=''><img src=".." /></a>

and my javascript is copied exactly from above.  any thoughts?

Comment: thanks for your effort . . i just figured out the latest issue and fixed it.. my jquery.js link had a typo in it :(.  all is good now

Answer (score 2):

```
var functionIWantToCall = function(){
    var wrappedLink = $(this);
    //some serious action
}

//this should be called on document ready
$("#myLinkId").click(functionIWantToCall);
```

If you need to get URL of picture, keep it in anchor`s href:

```
var functionIWantToCall = function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); //this one is important
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    //some serious action
}
```

Comment: my question is around how i can have the javascript pic up the picNumberLink variable now that its not inline

Comment: Add it to hidden field next to link, then - in functionIWantToCall use "var picNumberLink = wrappedLink.next().val()"

Comment: that seem like a kluge but if there is no more elegant way then thanks for the idea.  what would be the syntax of it, just a regular hidden html tag

Comment: <input type='hidden' value='<%= Model.PictureUrl %>' />

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$('#LinkID').click(function() {
    viewer.show($(this).attr('picNumber'));
});

});
```

You can add an attribute called picNumber to your hyperlink tag and set this is your mvc view

The link in your view might look something like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Index", new { id = "LINKID", picNumber = 1 }) %>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){}) can be abreviated to $(function(){})

Comment: for this to work, would i need the following

<a href="" picNumber+'3'><img src=".."></a>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're able to change the HTML you output, can't you put the picNumberLink in the `id` or `class` attribute?

HTML:

```
<a href="..." id="piclink-242" class="view foo-242"><img src="..."/></a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  // using the id attribute:
  $('.view').click(function() {
    viewer.show(+/-(\d+)/.exec(this.id)[1]);
  });

  // or using the class attribute:
  $('.view').click(function() {
    viewer.show(+/(^|\s)foo-(\d+)(\s|$)/.exec(this.className)[2]);
  });
}}
```

Comment: Just realised this is very much like karim79's answer... I think we need to see *me*'s HTML